# Python Webelement to .text selenium

Tags: python, selenium, qwebelement

I use Selenium,

I would like to know how to retrieve the two values ​​result.name and result.prix under value 'text' and be able to save in text format I find myself with the code below with two webelement value which is displayed only on my console but I can not save them.

Thanks for your help.

```py
from selenium import webdriver


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.ldlc.com/')

barre_de_recherche=driver.find_element_by_id("search_search_text")
barre_de_recherche.send_keys('Processeur socket 1200')


bouton_recherche=driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit")
bouton_recherche.click()


recuperation_nom=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title-3")
recuperation_prix=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price")


for resultat_nom in recuperation_nom:
    print(resultat_nom.text)

for resultat_prix in recuperation_prix:
    print(resultat_prix.text)
```